# Error in Spark SQL query after Spark version upgrade

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have very simple Spark SQL query for Hive table

```
spark.sql("OPTIMIZE METADATA IN t_space.table_name")
```

And it worked fine in 2.4.
After Spark version upgrade to 3.2 this query started throwing exception

```
mismatched input 'IN' expecting {<EOF>, ';'}(line 1, pos 18)
```

Is there are some syntax changed in Spark 3.+ versions?

Comment: I found the reason why this happened. 
I have changed spark_catalog on org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkSessionCatalog. 
And it is not supporting "OPTIMIZE METADATA IN ..." query